# cast {reshape}: using variables instead of the columns' name

Tags: r, variables, reshape

Say I have a dataframe:

```
data <- data.frame(id=c(1,2,2,2), 
                   code=c("A","B","A","B"), 
                   area=c(23.1,56.0,45.8,78.5))
```

and this line of code that's working fine:

```
df<-cast(data,id~code,fun.aggregate=sum)
```

Then I create the following variables:

```
ID <- "id"

CODE <- "code"
```

and use the variables as arguments in the cast function:

```
df <- cast(data, ID~CODE, fun.aggregate=sum)
```

Then I get the following error:

```
Error: Casting formula contains variables not found in molten data: ID, CODE
```

How can I use variables instead of the columns' name with the cast function?

Answer (score 4):

You need to construct a formula:

```
cast(data, as.formula(paste(ID, CODE, sep="~")), fun.aggregate=sum)
```

However, package reshape has been superseded by package reshape2 (have a look at its function `dcast` and see @Ananda Mahto's comment). The `reshape` function in base R might also be of interest to you.

Comment: +1. Maybe mention that if they were using "reshape2" they can use `get`: The following seems to work `dcast(data, get(ID) ~ get(CODE), fun.aggregate=sum)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use do.call() as well:

```
do.call("cast", args = list(data = data, formula = paste(ID, '~', Code), fun.aggregate = "sum"))
```

Arguments can (but don't have to) be delivered as strings.